failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Im trying to build my flutter project but am getting this error, any help is much appreciated.
Im running via visual studio code not through android studio.
thanks
`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_mlkit_commons:verifyReleaseResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR: C:\Users\samue\Downloads\memory\build\google_mlkit_commons\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:221: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
`


Possible duplicates of this. If you believe your question is different, please provide more details explaining why it is not.

This question is similar to: Message "error: resource android:attr/lStar not found". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
